# turn off drag in particle/explode?

Tags: particles, physics

I have a moving, exploding object and the parts always slow down as if affected by drag.  I have turned off all drag in the particle panel, and changed the number of particles to force a re-compute but the particles (and hence parts) still suffer significant velocity decay.  What could the source of this be?

My particle settings are:

Normal:1.0 Object:1.0

Physics:Newtonian Drag:0, Damp:0

Field Weights panel has all values set to 0.0

I can understand rear-facing polygons slowing down (normal velocity component) but I cannot get front-facing polygons to keep moving forward.  The original motion of the object is key-framed.  I don't have any physics on the object beyond the particle/explode.

Anyone know what I am missing?